# XML UTF-8 with special characters returns invalid characters

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I've tried to read up on this but to no avail.

Here goes, I make a call to an API which returns a city name from a postal code.
The return is in XML-format like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PostalCodeQueryResponse>
  <Response valid="true" postalCodeType="POBOX">OSLO</Response>   
</PostalCodeQueryResponse>
```

Which is then read and put in a textbox.

However, if the response uses some special characters like åäö for instance, the result
is completely different. Then I'm left with this instead:

```
<PostalCodeQueryResponse>
  <Response valid="true" postalCodeType="NORMAL">JÃ–NKÃ–PING</Response>
</PostalCodeQueryResponse>
```

Now JÃ–NKÃ–PING, should be JÖNKÖPING, but the Ö in this case turns into Ã–

I'm pretty sure it's because the XML file uses UTF-8 and I'm trying to read it as ISO-8859-1. So, after looking around at this magnificent site I stumbled upon this Little snippet:

```
Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;

byte[] utfBytes = utf8.GetBytes(location.Value.ToString());
byte[] isoBytes = Encoding.Convert(utf8, iso, utfBytes);

string city = iso.GetString(isoBytes);
```

But using this returns the same JÃ–NKÃ–PING in the textbox.

Where am I doing things wrong? Any ideas?

Comment: You already figured out what you are doing wrong: »I'm pretty sure it's because the XML file uses UTF-8 and I'm trying to read it as ISO-8859-1.« Short answer: Don't do that and read as UTF-8.

Comment: Yes, but how? If I try to just read out the value as a string without doing any kind of modification to it, it'll still return jibberish.

Comment: Well, in all fairness, I am using System.Xml the above code snippet is merely to illustrate how I'm trying to get the Unicode characters to be the Nordic characters I want them to be.